# Why when I start up my PC, many websites fail to be loaded

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, internet-connection, utorrent

Every time I start my PC, for the first five minutes, not all website load. Facebook and Google work but others not. After five minutes, all websites work again.

While µTorrent is open, none – or very few – websites work. After I close it, slowly more websites begin to load. Only after fifteen minutes, all websites work normally.

What could I do to improve my situation?

> This webpage is not available
>
> The server at files01.techspot.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.
>
> DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.
>
> Here are some suggestions:
>
> - Reload this webpage later.
> - Check your Internet connection. Restart any router, modem, or other network devices you may be using.
> - Check your DNS settings. Contact your network administrator if you're not sure what this means.
>   -Try disabling network prediction by following these steps: Go to the Chrome menu > Settings > Show advanced settings... and deselect "Predict network actions to improve page load performance." If this does not resolve the issue, we recommend selecting this option again for improved performance.
> - Add Google Chrome as a permitted program in your firewall's or antivirus software's settings. If it is already a permitted program, try deleting it from the list of permitted programs and adding it again.
> - If you use a proxy server, check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server, adjust your proxy settings: Go to the Chrome menu > Settings > Show advanced settings... > Change proxy settings... > LAN Settings and deselect the "Use a proxy server for your LAN" checkbox."

Comment: Are you connected directly through the internet, or via a router?

Comment: As to your first question, what browser and how many tabs? I have many tabs open on Firefox and there is quite a delay before all work. Facebook is one that works quickly.

Comment: router. I just open a blank browser and go to a webpage at the time. Google chrome

Comment: Could you try changing your DNS servers in Windows to 8.8.8.8 (Network and Sharing Center / Change Adapter Settings / Right Click interface / Properties / IPv4 / Use the following DNS Server).  This will determine whether it is your specific DNS server or a general problem.

Comment: I don't have the " Use the following DNS Server" setting; I just set my preferred dns and saved. Now what I might do to determine the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A BitTorrent client opens up a large number of connections and may cause your router to reach its maximum connection limit.

Now, I haven't use Utorrent, but most torrent clients have a possibility to limit the number of connections they allow. Try to reduce this number.

Alternatively, if you router has a configurable max number of connections, try to increase this number (be aware that the router may not be able to handle this performance-wise though).

Comment: I cannot improve the number of max connections on netgear cvg834g. On utorrent i have tried to change the number of connections and sometime is better or worse, but there are always sites failing to load.

Comment: Do you have the same problems with other computers / devices on your network?

Comment: I will try soon and I will tell you. But I remember that while my pc didn't working because of utorrent, my phone still worked.